# Which power supply choose for lineal actuators?

Tags: power-supply, motor, dc-motor, current-source, actuator

I have two actuators each of them with the following characteristics:  16 inch, 12v, load 750 N, travel speed 10mm / s, duty cycle 25%

BUT Current Draw is not specified, and I have no access to the datasheet.

I think in some scenarios:

-> let's say each actuator is of 2.5 Amps then I need a power supply of 5A Amperes.

-> let's say each actuator is of 4 Amps then I need a power supply of 8A

-> let's say each actuator if 6.5A Then I need a power supply of 13A

The thing is I dont know the Max Current Draw of each actuator, then my doubt is:

- What happens if the current of my power supply is too much bigger than the current I need for the lineal actuators. Let's say the lineal actuators need for both 5A and my power supply is of 10 A.
- What happens if the current of my power supply is too much lower than the current I need for the lineal actuators. Let's say the lineal actuators need for both 13A and my power supply is of 10 A.

Then I don't know what happens in that scenarios, and also in muy situation Which power supply would be the more convenient to buy?

Thanks in Advance.

Best Regards

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Comment: Thanks, I see the selected answer but it does not answered this scenario...... What happens if the current of my power supply is too much lower than the current I need for the lineal actuators. Let's say the lineal actuators need for both 13A and my power supply is of 10 A.

Comment: I will check the other answers..

Comment: If you cannot find Motor resistance from site or supplier, walk away or gamble and buy it